# extra space error on only 1 page of Bootstrap bavbar

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar that is showing a blank space when the navbar is shrinks smaller. There is a space from top to bottom between Home and Contact. Can you help me delete that gap? It doesn't show on the home or Honura page. Thank you

It only shows on this page:
http://vinylbrothersnh.com/honura.html
This is the sitemap page if you need it:
http://vinylbrothersnh.com/sitemap.xml

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg text-danger"><a class="navbar-brand m-2" href="#">Vinyl Brothers NH</a><button class="navbar-toggler m-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbar-custom" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button><div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse"><ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto"><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li><li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="honura.html">HONURA CREW</a></li></ul><ul class="navbar-nav flex-row"><li class="nav-item m-1"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/786555175173027" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="HONURA CREW Facebook page"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></a></li><li class="nav-item m-1"><a class="nav-link" href="tel:1-603-418-5562" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Call Us"><i class="fas fa-phone-square fa-lg"></i></a></li></ul></div></nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the '>' characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You have an extra `>` symbol that take up a block space, it is hard to see because of its color

try this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg text-danger"><a class="navbar-brand m-2" href="#">Vinyl Brothers NH</a><button class="navbar-toggler m-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbar-custom" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  <div
    class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="honura.html">HONURA CREW</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
      <li class="nav-item m-1"><a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/786555175173027" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="HONURA CREW Facebook page"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item m-1"><a class="nav-link" href="tel:1-603-418-5562" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Call Us"><i class="fas fa-phone-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know how I missed that

Comment: Yeah, it is hard to see just with the view. You can try Dev Console (f12) and inspect the element to know the structure of the elements. I do that a lot of times.